# 'SelectList' issue on .cshtml file giving directive missing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. Hence, I am trying some sample code by watching CRUD operations videos on YouTube.

When I am trying to populate dropdown list in a `.cshtml` file, I am getting an error for select list.

I am unable to understand which directive I have to use for this select list issue.

Have also included helpers here.

Error:

> 'SelectList' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'SelectList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`.cshtml` markup:

```
@model MVC_Crude_SP.Models.Employee

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>EmpModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="panel-body">
            
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Empid, new SelectList { Model.empList, "Empid", "EMP_NAME", new { @class = "form-control select2", @required = "true", @id = "divDropDown" } })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

`EmpModel.cs` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MVC_Crude_SP.Repository;
using System.Collections;

namespace MVC_Crude_SP.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Empid { get; set; }
        public string EMP_NAME { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Employee> empList { get; set; }

        public Employee()
        {
            Empid = 0;
            empList = new List<Employee>();
        }
    }
}
```

`EmpRep.cs` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using MVC_Crude_SP.Models;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MVC_Crude_SP.Repository
{
    public class EmpRep
    {
        SqlDbHelper db = new SqlDbHelper();

        // To Add Employee details
        public List<Employee> GetEmpList()
        {
            DataTable sodt;
            Employee emp;

            List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

            SqlDbHelper db = new SqlDbHelper();

            try
            {
                sodt = db.GetTableBySP("SP_DisplayEmp");

                // Division
                foreach (DataRow row in sodt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "EMP_CD", "EMP_NAME").Rows)
                {
                    emp = new Employee();
                    emp.Empid = Convert.ToInt32(row["EMP_CD"]);
                    emp.EMP_NAME = row["EMP_NAME"].ToString();
                    empList.Add(emp);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                sodt = null;
                emp = null;
                db = null;
            }

            return empList;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me on how to proceed further.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: ok. thanks for bringing to my notice. I will keep this in mind next time.

Comment: We got same problem and i found a workaround I used viewbag EX:  ViewBag.StaffList =  new SelectList(Staff.ToList(), "staffid", "staffname"); and my dropdown @Html.DropDownList("Staff", ViewBag.StaffList as SelectList, new { id = "ddlstaff", @class = "form-control" })

Comment: have tried that too but giving same error still.. Can you please mention parameter names  in syntax..like below    ViewBag.StaffList = new SelectList(Staff.ToList(), "staffid", "staffname"); here ViewBag.StaffList  is list in dropdown..etc..